# Get the parent node on the basis of single child element with specific attribute

Tags: linq

I am having below xml

```
    <component>
                <!--Active Problems-->
                <section>
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.11.83.103" assigningAuthorityName="HITSP/C83"/>
                    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.6" assigningAuthorityName="IHE PCC"/>
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.11" assigningAuthorityName="HL7 CCD"/>

                </section>
            </component>
<component> 
<!--Medications-->
                <section>
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.11.83.112" assigningAuthorityName="HITSP/C83"/>
                    <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.19" assigningAuthorityName="IHE PCC"/>
                    <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.8" assigningAuthorityName="HL7 CCD"/>
                </section>
            </component>
```

From this i want to read section node which contains templateId node and which have root attribute's value is 2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.8. how it can be done using linq ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this easily using Linq-to-XML.

Use this:

```
using System.Xml.Linq;  // required namespace for linq-to-xml
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(@"mypath\myxmlfile.xml");
```

to load the XML file into an `XDocument` object.

Then use the following query:

```
 var section = from s in doc.Descendants("section")
               where s.Elements("templateId")
                      .Any(t => t.Attribute("root").Value == "2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.8")
               select s;
```

to get the required `<section>` element.

**Output:**

```
- <section>
     <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.3.88.11.83.112" assigningAuthorityName="HITSP/C83" /> 
     <templateId root="1.3.6.1.4.1.19376.1.5.3.1.3.19" assigningAuthorityName="IHE PCC" /> 
     <templateId root="2.16.840.1.113883.10.20.1.8" assigningAuthorityName="HL7 CCD" /> 
  </section>
```

Comment: I have tried to apply this solution but it gives me section as null

Comment: @Audumbar I have tested prior to posting and it works OK. *Note* that you have to place a *root* node to the XML you posted, otherwise `Linq-to-XML` *will not be able to parse it*.

Comment: yes output you posted is correct and proper as I wanted but I am getting message as "Enumeration yielded no results". May be something is wrong from my side hence it is saying like this..

Comment: @Audumbar [1] Did you try to place a root node, e.g. like `<components>`, in your XML file? [2] What do you get if you remove entirely the `Where` clause from the linq query? [3] First try the code with the exact xml piece you have posted (after adding root node of course).